# Iteration order of a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

After reading the documentation for `LinkedHashMap` (and having used it several times), I'm still not clear about one of its properties...is the iteration order for a `LinkedHashMap`:

1. the same as insertion order for `entrySet()`, `keySet()`, and `values()`, or
2. the same as insertion order for `entrySet()` and `keySet()` but not `values()`, or
3. only the same as insertion order for `entrySet()`?

I imagine the third scenario to be unlikely, but I would like to know if anyone knows if (1) or (2) is true since iteration over `values()` is probably a rare use case.

Comment: After looking the source code, I realized that all three iterators respect insertion order.

Comment: What about simply trying an example?

Comment: Proof by anecdotal evidence doesn't really hold water for me...I ended up consulting the source code. Thanks!

Comment: @MrSmith42: This is the type of question for which trying an example will likely tell you very little of value. You could easily get a false positive -- the insertion order happened to remain the same for a given example, but wouldn't for a more complicated or longer-running example.

Comment: Not that checking the source is much better. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LinkedHashMap` respects insertion order; so the first choice is the good.

A `Map` being a set of `Map.Entry` objects, options 2 and 3 would be rather strange ;)

Comment: The set of `Map.Entry` objects makes sense, although I never realized it was that way. I thought it would be possible for the doubly linked list to only run through the keys, for example. It does appear obvious now that I've looked at the source.

Comment: Well, `.entrySet()` returns a `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>`. And it would be rather sad if you inserted k1, v1 and then k2, v2 all that to read v2 when you read k1 :p

Comment: Also, you can't possibly iterate over a `LinkedHashMap` without going through `entrySet()`, `keySet()`, or `values()` -- it doesn't exactly have an "insertion order" on its own.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, meant "iteration order."

Comment: To clarify, `keySet()` and `values()` collections **are** iterated in the order inserted.